# Spark Scala create external hive table not working with location as a variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, external

I am trying to create Hive external table from Spark application and passing location as a variable to the SQL command. It doesn't create Hive table and I don't see any errors.

```
 val location = "/home/data"
 hiveContext.sql(s"""CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable(id STRING,name STRING) PARTITIONED BY (city string)  STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION '${location}' """)
```

Comment: Did you try `hdfs dfs -ls /home/data` to ensure it were not created? What does that return?

Answer (score 2):

Spark only supports creating ***managed*** tables. And even then there are severe restrictions: it does not support *dynamically partitioned* tables.

TL;DR you can ***not*** create ***external*** tables through Spark. Spark *can* ***read*** them

Comment: It won't work through Spark application.But works within Hive

Comment: @GG Updated my answer : remembered this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version had this limitations.
I using Spark 1.6, Hive 1.1.

I am able to create the external table, please follow below:

```
var query = "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE avro_hive_table ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'TBLPROPERTIES   ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs://localdomain/user/avro/schemas/activity.avsc')    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'    OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'    LOCATION    '/user/avro/applog_avro'"
var hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc);

hiveContext.sql(query);
var df = hiveContext.sql("select count(*) from avro_hive_table");
```